# TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories'

Tags: python, pandas

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

priority_dtype = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=['LOW', 'MEDIUM', 'HIGH'], ordered=True)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories'
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce in a fresh REPL. Is it possible you're running an ancient version of Pandas and/or Python?

Comment: Using Pandas version 0.20.3